# Differentiable and injective function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives

I'm having trouble with the following exercise:

Let $f:U \to \mathbb{R}^{M}$ be a differentiable application in $a \in U \subset \mathbb{R}^{N}$, an open set. If $f'(a) \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^N,\mathbb{R}^{M})$ is injective, then there are $c,\delta>0$, such that for every $v \in \mathbb{R}^{N}$ with $|v|<\delta$ implies $|f(a+v)-f(a)| \geq c|v|$

My hint was to define a continuous function $F:S(0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$, with $F(v) = |f'(a)v|$.

I know that in a compact a continuous function has a minimum $v_{0}$, such as $F(v) \geq F(v_{0})$, for every $v \in S(0,1)$, and that $F(v_{0}) > 0$. Otherwise, if $F(v_{0}) = 0$, then $f'(a)v_{0}=0$, but $f'(a)$ is injective, so $v_{0} =0$, which is absurd as $v_{0} \in S(0,1)$.

I also know that, as $f$ is differentiable in $a \in U$, and for $v \in \mathbb{R}^{N}$ with $|v|<\delta$, $|r(v)| = |f(a+v)-f(a)-f'(a)v| < c|v|$

Now I don't know how to proceed. Help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon:=\frac12\min_{S(0,1)} F>0$. By the definition of differentiability you can find $\delta>0$ such that 
$$|f(a+v)-f(a)-df(a)(v)|\le \varepsilon |v|$$ for all $0<|v|\le\delta$. Then
$$|f(a+v)-f(a)|\ge |df(a)(v)|-|f(a+v)-f(a)-df(a)(v)|\ge 2\varepsilon|v|-\varepsilon|v|=\varepsilon|v|.$$